# Как узнать источник перехода на страницу?

Tags: php

Все в пределах одного сайта.
Идея такова: попал человек на страницу 404, сразу запускается скрипт, посылает на e-mail админу страницу и ссылку откуда попали на 404.

Вопрос - такое достижимо? Можно узнать страницу и ссылку перехода?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
getenv("HTTP_REFERER");
```

---

```
<?php
$a = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
if (isset ($a))
{
echo "Вы пришли со страницы:" .$a; //вместо вывода, делаем отправку(mail()).
}
?>
```